# how to replace unwanted characters [] when loading json file in Python?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to load a json file using the following code:

```
with open('tweets_036.jsonl') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

but I get the following error msg:

```
JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 24289 column 2 (char 1088180)
```

when i take a look at the file/line 24289, I can see that [] is causing the problem:

```
        "favorited": false
    }
][
    {
        "retweeted": false,
```

Comparing to previous lines, it should be :

```
        "favorited": false
    },
    {
        "retweeted": false,
```

FYI, the data relates to tweets, 'retweeted' is normally the first element of a new tweet whilst 'favorited' is the last one.

Thank you in advance if you can please help.

Comment: You can't use `json.load()` if your data is not `json`.

Comment: it is json format, but there's a problem with specific lines in it..

Comment: If it were in json format, then `json.load()` would load it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`str.replace()`](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-string-replace-method-replacing-python-strings/)

**tweets_036.jsonl**:

```
[
    {
      "favorited": false
    }
][
    {
      "retweeted": false
    }
]
```

**Hence**:

```
import json

with open('tweets_036.jsonl', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
    clean = content.replace('][', ',')  # cleanup here
    json_data = json.loads(clean)

print(json_data)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[{'favorited': False}, {'retweeted': False}]
```

Comment: PS if that's useful to anyone I only added the following line to load into DF: 
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(json_data)

Answer (score 1):

You cloud try: python's **re.sub**

It uses this format:

```
result = re.sub(pattern, replacement, input)
```

So in your case it would be something like this:

```
clean_data = re.sub('][', '', data)
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `,` and not `''`

Answer (score 0):

Had that same issue a little while back. For some reason twitter returns multiple json structures within a list, but does not separate the lists with the comma, so took each json element between the `[ ]`, and appended them into an actual list. So you'll end up with a list of json structured data. Here's the solution I used a while back:

```
import json

filename='C:/tweets_043.json'


with open(filename) as json_file:  
    data_str = json_file.read()
    data_str = data_str.split('[',1)[-1]
    data_str = data_str.rsplit(']',1)[0]
    data_str = data_str.split('][')

clean_data = []
need_cleaning = False
for i, each in enumerate(data_str):
    if need_cleaning == True:
        hold_string = hold_string + '][' + each
        if each.strip()[-1] != '}':
            continue
        else:
            clean_data.append(hold_string.strip())
            need_cleaning = False
            continue

    if each.strip()[-1] != '}':
        hold_string = data_str[i]
        need_cleaning = True
        continue

    else:
        clean_data.append(each.strip())
        need_cleaning = False





data = []
error = []
for jsonStr in clean_data:

    jsonStr = '[' + jsonStr + ']'
    try:
        temp_data = json.loads(jsonStr.strip())
        for each in temp_data:
            data.append(each)
    except:
        print ('error')
        error.append(jsonStr)
```

Parses everything except the one (where you also stated in the comments). Where the issue is:

```
                        "large": {
                            [{
                                    "is_quote_status": false,
                                    "filter_level": "low",
                                    "in_reply_to_screen_name": "Huawei",
                                    "display_text_range": [
                                        8,
                                        53
                                    ],
```

I don't see anywhere where the first square bracket is closed, or at least where it should be closed.

Comment: Hi Chitown, you helped me a while back with this and had suggested the above. The problem is when I use the above i get an error in some cases as some records also have ][ in them:

Comment: "description": "[iphone\u30a2\u30d7\u30ea\u3092\u3055\u304c\u3059]\u306b\u5f53\u305f\u308a\u524d\u306e\u691c\u7d22\u3092\niphone\u30a2\u30d7\u30ea \u8d85!\u691c\u7d22\u306f[\u30ad\u30fc\u30ef\u30fc\u30c9][\u8a55\u4fa1][\u8a55\u4fa1\u6570][\u30ea\u30ea\u30fc\u30b9\u65e5][\u4fa1\u683c][\u30ab\u30c6\u30b4\u30ea]\u306a\u3069\u306e\u8907\u5408\u6761\u4ef6\u306b\u3088\u308b\u30a2\u30d7\u30ea\u306e\u691c\u7d22\u304c\u53ef\u80fd\u3067\u3059\n\u3053\u306e\u30a2\u30ab\u30a6\u30f3\u30c8\u3067\u306f\u57cb\u3082\u308c\u305f\u30a2\u30d7\u30ea\u3092\u30e9\u30f3\u30c0\u30e0\u306b",

Comment: so we'd want to replace ][ only when it's on a 'seperate' tweet

Comment: Oh hey @tezzaaa. ya didn't realise it was you! Oh ya I see what you mean. This is only my assumption, but you'd want those to also have a comma between them. Is it possible to send that json file again with this new records in it to play around with?

Comment: the solutions in the example in these comments, you'd want to replace `][`, with `],[`. But in the OP, i'm thinking the solutions by DirtyBit, to replace `][`, with `,` should work.

Comment: Hi, I tried again with DirtyBit's answer and it seems to work! for completeness here is the code I use: with open('tweets_036.jsonl', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
clean = content.replace('][', ',')  # cleanup here
json_data = json.loads(clean)
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(json_data)

Comment: Hi, actually i've tried the code on a bigger file and it falls over, I get the following error message: ValueError: Expecting property name: line 6991314 column 8 (char 312487607). I will print below the related lines from near 6991314 ..

Comment: is that within the file you sent?

Comment: ['                            "resize": "crop"',
 '                        },',
 '                        "large": {',
 '       [',
 '    {',
 '        "is_quote_status": false,']

Comment: so it does not like: '    {',

Comment: Ya there seems to be something out of place there. I was able to parse the rest of it. I'll post the code I used that parsed it, including a part that will let you look at the block that's causing that issue. It's not following the valid json format, so might just be an issue on their end, not yours. But not entirely sure.